# Test asynchronous nested component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme, redux-thunk

Say I have the following wrapper component:

```
'use strict'

import React, {PropTypes, PureComponent} from 'react'
import {update} from '../../actions/actions'
import LoadFromServerButton from '../LoadFromServerButton'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

export class FooDisplay extends PureComponent {
  render () {
    return (
      <p>
        <span className='foo'>
          {this.props.foo}
        </span>
        <LoadFromServerButton updateFunc={this.props.update} />
      </p>
    )
  }
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {foo: state.foo.foo}
}

FooDisplay.propTypes = {
  foo: PropTypes.string
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    update: (foo) => dispatch(update(foo))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FooDisplay)
```

and the following inner component:

```
'use strict'

import React, {PropTypes, PureComponent} from 'react'
import {get} from '../../actions/actions'
import ActiveButton from '../ActiveButton'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

export class LoadFromServerButton extends PureComponent {
  doUpdate () {
    return this.props.get().then(this.props.updateFunc)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ActiveButton action={this.doUpdate.bind(this)} actionArguments={[this.props.foo]} text='fetch serverside address' />
    )
  }
}

export const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {foo: state.foo.foo}
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    get: () => dispatch(get())
  }
}

LoadAddressFromServerButton.propTypes = {
  updateFunc: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoadFromServerButton)
```

`ActiveButton` is a very thin wrapper around a button with an onclick and arguments destructuring.

Now lets say that I my get action is written as follows:

```
export const get = () => dispatch => http('/dummy_route')
      .spread((response, body) => dispatch(actOnThing(update, body)))
```

Now if I write a test like so:

```
/* global window, test, expect, beforeAll, afterAll, describe */

'use strict'

import React from 'react'
import FooDisplay from './index'
import {mount} from 'enzyme'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from '../../store/configureStore'
import nock, {uriString} from '../../config/nock'
import _ from 'lodash'


const env = _.cloneDeep(process.env)
describe('the component behaves correctly when integrating with store and reducers/http', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    nock.disableNetConnect()
    process.env.API_URL = uriString
  })

  afterAll(() => {
    process.env = _.cloneDeep(env)
    nock.enableNetConnect()
    nock.cleanAll()
  })

  test('when deep rendering, the load event populates the input correctly', () => {
    const store = configureStore({
      address: {
        address: 'foo'
      }
    })
    const display = mount(<Provider store={store}><FooDisplay /></Provider>,
        {attachTo: document.getElementById('root')})
    expect(display.find('p').find('.address').text()).toEqual('foo')
    const button = display.find('LoadFromServerButton')
    expect(button.text()).toEqual('fetch serverside address')
    nock.get('/dummy_address').reply(200, {address: 'new address'})
    button.simulate('click')
  })
})
```

This results in:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080
```

After a little bit of thinking, this is due to the fact that the test does not return a promise, as the button click causes the promise to fire under the hood, therefore, `afterAll` runs immediatly, cleans nock, and a real http connection goes over the wire.

How do I test this case? I don't seem to have an easy way to return the correct promise... How do I test updates to the DOM resulting from these updates?

Comment: It seems like you are not dealing with a rejected promise, but only when it is fulfilled. Did you intend to simulate an off-line environment? What happens if you remove nock.disableNetConnect() and its counterpart? If your test is doing any async action, you should include the done parameter and call it when the async action is finished. As an alternative, you could also return a promise for the test. See https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html

Comment: yeah no I understand, but how can I return the correct promise? The button click triggers an asynchronous action, and it is unclear to me how to enforce  that the right test is returned from the test

Comment: Where's the definition of the "update" function? I feel like this.props.getFoo() was meant to be this.props.get(), inside LoadFromServerButton's doUpdate function ?

Comment: Yes you are right, getFoo was meant to be get and I have updated my snippet accordingly. Update is defined identically to get, but on a post rather than a get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to mock only one method of the imported module, use .requireActual(...)

```
jest.mock('../your_module', () => ({
    ...(jest.requireActual('../your_module')),
    YourMethodName: () => { return { type: 'MOCKED_ACTION'}; }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned the problem is that you dont have the promise to return from test. So to make `get` return a know promise you can just mock `get` directly without using nock:

```
import {get} from '../../actions/actions'
jest.mock('../../actions/actions', () => ({get: jest.fn}))
```

this will replace the action module with an object `{get: jestSpy}`

in your test you can then create a promise and let `get` return this and also return this promise from your test:

```
it('', ()=>{
  const p = new Promise.resolve('success')
  get.mockImplementation(() => p)//let get return the resolved promise
  //test you suff
  return p
})
```